# Python packaging: Boost library as dependency

Tags: python, boost, cython, pypi, python-packaging

Assume that someone wants to package a Python (Cython) library that depends on the C++ boost library.

What is the best way to configure the `setup.py` so that the user is properly informed that it is required to install the boost library (i.e., `apt-get install libboost-dev` in Ubuntu, etc in other OSes)? Or is it a better practice to include the boost library in the python package distribution?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a good way to detect this at runtime. Maybe try compiling a simple test program that uses boost and see if compilation fails?

Comment: @ngoldbaum I have done this already. The question is more on the best practices with external dependencies like boost. In a nutshell, do you include the boost library in the package (headers only) or you report an error during the python package installation to the user.

Comment: I agree with Danny’s answer. If no wheel is available then you should error out of your setup.py with a useful error message if a needed external library is unavailable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is better asked as

> What is the best way to distribute a Python extension including
>   an external library dependency.

This is better dealt with binary wheel packages.

User does not need to know anything about `setup.py`, which is used for building and installing source code. User just needs to download and install a binary wheel package.

Including just the header files does not solve the problem of needing the library to build with and link to. It also opens up issues with version incompatibilities.

So `setup.py` need not have anything special about any of this, it just needs to know where to find headers which will be a sub-dir in your project if the library is included and which libraries to link with.

The documentation should include instructions on how to build from source, for which more than just boost is needed (python header files, appropriate compilers etc).

Tools like [auditwheel](https://github.com/pypa/auditwheel) then take care of bundling external library dependencies into the binary wheel, so end-users need not have the library installed to use your package.

See also [manylinux](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux) for distributing binary Python extensions and [this demo project](https://github.com/pypa/python-manylinux-demo).